# How do I make an button display a dialog when I click on it?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have 12 buttons and each button has a name of someone in my family on it. I want to make the buttons functional. When the user clicks on their name i want a message to pop up and say "Hello (whatever name)!" My code is below. Can you please tell me how to make these buttons function the way I want them to. Thanks in advance.

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;

    public class NameButtons{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pick A Name");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,6));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Stephanie"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Dwayne"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Jennifer"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Brian"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Joseph"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Justin"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Raine"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Hunter"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Grayson"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Abel"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Janice"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Bob"));
        buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
        containerPanel.add(buttonPanel);

        frame.getContentPane().add(containerPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: use an ActionListener

Comment: Use Jbutton ActionListener.

Comment: http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-swing-tutorials/278-how-add-actionlistener-jbutton-swing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Stephanie"));
```

Do:

```
JButton stephanieButton = new JButton("Stephanie");
stephanieButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Do something
    }
});
buttonPanel.add(stephanieButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using an anonymous object, but first creating the object.

```
JButton button = new JButton("Name");
```

Then you can all the `addActionListener` method.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // This is the code that is ran when the button is clicked.
        System.out.println("Hello name");
    }
});
```

**What am I doing?**

Well, what you're telling the button is to use this `ActionListener` object. Now, because `ActionListener` contains the abstract method, `actionPerformed`, you need to provide code for that method. Hence, you pass it the method with the code.

**Using one of your buttons as an example**

```
JButton stephButton = new JButton("Stephanie");
stepButton.setVisible(true);
// Create the button.
stephButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // Message printed to stephanie.
        System.out.println("Hello Stephanie!");
    }
```

Comment: What all would I need to erase from my code to get this to work. I am a beginner and this is really confusing.

Comment: If you look at the example I've given you for your buttons, copy and paste that into your code. Then add `stephButton` to your panel. When the program loads, give it a click!

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) shows one of the simplest ways about binding actions to UI elements.
You just need to set 'action' for a button and implement the actionPerformed handler which will be called if any UI element is clicked. You can distinguish buttons by reading e.getActionCommand().

Answer (score 0):

**Add action listeners to each of the button.**

```
JButton b1=new JButton("Stephanie");
JButton b2=new JButton("Dwayne");
buttonPanel.add(b1);
buttonPanel.add(b2);


b1.addActionListener(this);
b2.addActionListener(this);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == b1)
        {
          //Display Stephanie
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add action listeners to each of your buttons.  Personally, I would recommend that you create the buttons outside of the panel, and then add them in after you attach a button listener.

For example:

```
JButton Dwayne = new JButton("Dwayne");
Dwayne.addActionListener(this);
buttonPanel.add(Dwayne);
```

Here's a tutorial that may help you as well: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html